# Need translation for these Sanskrit verses in English

Tags: translation-request, sandhyavandanam

> *Aapo hi stha mayo bhuvah*
>
> *Ta na urje dadhaatana*
>
> *Mahe ranaya chaksase*
>
> *Yo vah sivatamo rasah*
>
> *Tasya bhajaya teha naha*
>
> *Usatiriva matarah*
>
> *Tasma aram gamama vah*
>
> *Yasya ksayaya jinvatha*
>
> *Aapo janayatha cha naha*

What do they mean in English?

Comment: You already got one answer. This site (scroll to the bottom) also gives the translation of the mantra -- http://onlinedarshan.com/stories/gayatri/ss.asp?id=205

Comment: this is cool. never seen this site

Comment: Give your sources, this is not a translation forum.

Comment: @swami vishwananda . the answer is in front of you. it was a response to the onlinedarshan.com

Answer (score 1):

This is part of Marjanam - Body & Mind Purification

Quoting from this document hosted by the [Hinduonline site](http://hinduonline.co/DigitalLibrary/SmallBooks/UpakarmaVidhanaSanEng.pdf)

> Meaning :
>
> It is well-known that you, the deities of water, are the
> cause of great happiness. Please nourish us with the divine vision
> which brings glory and loveliness. Please make us worthy of imbibing
> the auspicious bliss even as a mother feeds her children. We approach
> you with eagerness for that bliss to distribute which you have taken a
> form and are shining. Bestow on us the boon of a next life sanctified
> by knowledge.